# The probability that an M/M/c queue will be full within a given period of time

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process, queueing-theory

We have an M/M/c queue that models customers arriving at a store. The arrivals of customers are Poisson distributed with rate $\lambda=9$. There are three employees serving the customers. The time it takes to serve a customer is exponentially distributed with rate $\mu=0.75$ (i.e. mean $\frac{1}{0.75}=\frac{4}{3}$).
We say that an employer is idle if he is not currently serving a customer.

At a given point in time, the store is empty. What is the probability that during the next hour there will always be at least one idle employee? Alternatively, if we let $X(t)$ denote the number of customers in the system at time $t$, we are looking for the probability that $X(t)<3$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$ given that $X(0)=0$.

I am not sure how I should approach this problem. I am aware of the transition rate matrix and figured I could combine states 3 and above into one absorbing state, leaving me with the state space $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.  However I'm unsure how to utilize that.

Comment: Using the absorbing state, perhaps you can solve the ODE to find $p_i(t)$ for all $i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Then you want $1-p_3(1)$. Remember that in general CTMCs we have $p_j'(t) = -v_jp_j(t) + \sum_{i:i\neq j} p_i(t) q_{ij}$ where $v_j = \sum_{k:k\neq j} q_{jk}$.